# Oracle calling a function within DML

Tags: sql, oracle, function, dml

I have a function that takes in a string 'HH:MM:SS' and converts it to the number of seconds. See below example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CONVERT_TO_SECONDS( 
  i_date_string IN VARCHAR2 
)
RETURN INTEGER            
AS
 l_hours      NUMBER;
 l_minutes  NUMBER;
 l_seconds  NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT trim('"'
  FROM regexp_substr(i_date_string,'".*?"|[^:]+',1,1)) hours,
    trim('"'
  FROM regexp_substr(i_date_string,'".*?"|[^:]+',1,2)) minutes,
    trim('"'
  FROM regexp_substr(i_date_string,'".*?"|[^:]+',1,3)) seconds
      INTO l_hours ,
    l_minutes ,
    l_seconds
  FROM dual ;
return
     l_hours*3600 +  
     l_minutes*60 +
     l_seconds;
     
END;
/
    
SELECT CONVERT_TO_SECONDS('08:08:08') FROM DUAL;

CONVERT_TO_SECONDS('08:08:08')
29288
```

I have a procedure that works fine, which creates emp_attendance rows.

After the rows are created I am trying to update the end_date of each row with the number of seconds returned by the function. Is this possible? If so, how can I get past the syntax error on the update.

Thanks in advance to all that answer and for your help, patience and expertise.

My test CASE is below.

```
     
   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';

        CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE nt_date IS TABLE OF DATE;
/
       
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_dates_pipelined(
          p_from IN DATE,
          p_to   IN DATE
        )
        RETURN nt_date  PIPELINED   DETERMINISTIC
        IS
          v_start DATE := TRUNC(LEAST(p_from, p_to));
          v_end   DATE := TRUNC(GREATEST(p_from, p_to));
        BEGIN
         LOOP
            PIPE ROW (v_start);
            EXIT WHEN v_start >= v_end;
            v_start := v_start + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
          END LOOP;
          RETURN;
        END       generate_dates_pipelined;
/


        Create table employees(
          employee_id NUMBER(6), 
          first_name VARCHAR2(20),
          last_name VARCHAR2(20),
         card_num VARCHAR2(10),
          work_days VARCHAR2(7)
       );

        INSERT INTO employees (
         employee_id,
         first_name, 
         last_name,
         card_num,
         work_days
        )
        WITH names AS   ( 
          SELECT 1, 'John',     'Doe',      'D564311','YYYYYNN' FROM dual UNION ALL
          SELECT 2, 'Justin',     'Case',      'C224311','YYYYYNN' FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, 'Mike',     'Jones',      'J288811','YYYYYNN' FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 'Jane',     'Smith',      'S564661','YYYYYNN' FROM dual 
       ) SELECT * FROM names; 

  
        CREATE TABLE  emp_attendance(    
      seq_num NUMBER  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
            employee_id NUMBER(6),
            start_date DATE,
            end_date DATE,
            week_number NUMBER(2));


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_emp_attendance      (
      p_start_date  IN DATE,
      p_end_date    IN DATE
    )
    IS
   BEGIN

     INSERT INTO emp_attendance ( employee_id, start_date, end_date, week_number)
     SELECT  
          employee_id
          , start_date
          , start_date+NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(3600,43200)), 'SECOND') AS end_date
          , to_char(start_date,'WW') AS week_number 
     FROM (  -- Need subquery to generate end_date based on start_date. 
             SELECT e.employee_id, d.COLUMN_VALUE + NUMTODSINTERVAL(FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0,86399)), 'SECOND') AS start_date
               FROM   employees e
              CROSS JOIN TABLE( generate_dates_pipelined(p_start_date, p_end_date) ) d
          ) ed
          ;
END;
/

EXEC create_emp_attendance(SYSDATE, SYSDATE);


-- Having problem with this update 

update emp_attendance 
set end_date=start_date + NUMTODSINTERVAL
CONVERT_TO_SECONDS('08:08:08'),'SECOND';

-- Once the update is working the query below should show 8hrs 8mins 8sec for each row.

select  e.employee_id,
         e.first_name,
        e.last_name,

        trunc(sum(a.end_date - a.start_date) * 24) hours,

        trunc(mod(sum(a.end_date - a.start_date) * 24 * 60,60)) minutes,

        round(mod(sum(a.end_date - a.start_date) * 24 * 60 * 60,60)) seconds

  from  employees e,
           emp_attendance a

  where a.employee_id = e.employee_id 

AND start_date BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND
TRUNC(SYSDATE)+ (1-1/24/60/60)
 group by e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
  order by e.employee_id, e.first_name,
           e.last_name;
```

Comment: Please note: **MM** means month. Use **MI** for minutes. (I fixed this for you in a previous question, but I will let you do it now; it will help you remember this distinction.)

Comment: Also: since the input strings contain only digits and colon, and moreover the "tokens" aren't allowed to be empty (null), the regular expression can be much simpler: `\d+` means "one or more consecutive digits". And you don't need to trim double-quotes. In your earlier thread you said you were going to simplify the function yourself, but I don't see where you did that.

Comment: It's interesting that `NUMTODSINTERVAL` seems to be used correctly in `create_emp_attendance`, but incorrectly in the problem `update`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your function to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CONVERT_TO_SECONDS( 
  i_date_string IN VARCHAR2 
)
RETURN INTEGER DETERMINISTIC
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN ( TO_DATE(i_date_string, 'HH24:MI:SS')
         - TO_DATE('00:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')
         ) * 86400;
END;
/
```

Then you need brackets around the `NUMTODSINTERVAL` function arguments:

```sql
UPDATE emp_attendance 
SET end_date = start_date + NUMTODSINTERVAL( CONVERT_TO_SECONDS('08:08:08'),'SECOND' );
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ee00deea342b1a89a3385dc1eb719a16)*

Answer (score 1):

NUMTODSINTERVAL is a function.  So it needs to be used like this:

```
update emp_attendance
   set end_date=start_date + NUMTODSINTERVAL(CONVERT_TO_SECONDS('08:08:08'), 'SECOND')
;
```

Comment: while MTO solution fits my needs perfectly a good idea would be modifying MTO function to accept num_days parameter, DEFAULT 0 this way NUMTODSINTERVAL could always be used. This way there would be 1 method to handle 2 situations. Just food for thought. Thanks for your response and expertise

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create custom function, because Oracle already has it: [`to_dsinterval`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DSINTERVAL.html#GUID-DEBB41BD-9438-4558-A53E-428CE93C05D3). But you need to provide also a number of days, so add a zero before your time:

> ```
> select
>   sysdate,
>   sysdate + to_dsinterval('0 ' || '08:08:08') as sysdate_shifted
> from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> SYSDATE             | SYSDATE_SHIFTED    
> :------------------ | :------------------
> 2021-08-15 18:31:49 | 2021-08-16 02:39:57
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=12933a92c41a86b33afcbd3a0c520e69)*

Then your update will be:

```
update emp_attendance 
set end_date = start_date + to_dsinterval('0 ' || '08:08:08')
```